# What is the verb for "hacking" (as in computing) in Chinese?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests, loanwords

Using my dictionary and some research, I've found that there seems to be three words for "hacker" in Chinese. 黑客，骇客，and 红客. The first two look to just mean "hacker," while the third is a word for the implicitly state-supported private citizen in the PRC who hacks foreign enterprise out of nationalism. But does anyone know how to describe the verb for what these people do? My dictionary says to simply use 黑 or 骇, but what of the specific grammar cases when I need a two-syllable verb? Surely there's a better verb.

EDIT: After further searching, perhaps 侵入 would work? It seems to be a word with military connotations for "invade," but apparently can also mean to "gain unauthorized access."

Thanks.

Comment: 黑客 is the generally accepted term for a hacker. 骇客 is an alternative, but less common. 红客 is a "red hacker", hacking on behalf of the Chinese Communist state or its organizations. 黑 can be used as a verb, it is a loan word based on the phonetic and semantic ("black is illegal") similarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**黑** is the verb you are looking for.

**被黑了** is the common phrase form of "been hacked".

If you feel **黑** is too ambiguous you can add an object behind it to turn it into a VO (verb object) phrase: 黑电脑, etc.

Alternatively Oxford suggests:

> 5 COMPUTING, COLLOQUIAL
>
> 窃取
>
> to hack secret data from computers
>
> 从计算机里窃取机密资料

Personally I would just go with 黑 in this day and age.